# Regular Expression Replacer Not Working

Tags: javascript, regex

My problem is that I cannot get the code to remove mark tags around a word and keep the word there with the same capitalization. Here is my code:

```
function removeMark(tagName, Color) {
  var tagNameC = tagName.toUpperCase();
  var IndAry = tags.indexOf(tagNameC);
  tags.splice(IndAry, 1);
  var Notes = document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML;
  var MarkBack = new RegExp("/b" + tagName + "/b", "gim")
  var MarkBackTo = "<mark class=" + Color + ">" + MarkBack + "</mark>"
  var AfterRep = Notes.replace(MarkBackTo, "$1");
  document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML = AfterRep;
  var list = document.getElementById("myList");
  var idmarker = "MarkID" + tagName;
  var ElementID = document.getElementById(idmarker);
  MarkList.removeChild(ElementID);
}
```

tagName is the word inside the mark tags. The mark tags have a class that is a constant but the word inside may not always be due to capitalization. I am inputting `tagName` and `Color` through the input. 
I am guessing it has to do with the regex since I do not know much about it and I cannot find anything wrong with my javascript. If anyone can see what is going wrong it would be extremely helpful!

Comment: `new RegExp("\\b" + tagName + "\\b", "gi")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Doesn't work

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying  to do with help of sample input text and desired output. say this is my string e.g. `<mark class="color">content</mark>` and mention your desired output

Comment: That is what it would look like before the replace. My desired output would be `content` but if the original like of text was `<mark class="color">coTNeNt</mark>` it would come out as `CoTNeNt`

Comment: Your comment on my answer disappeared. Answered anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input = '<mark class="color">coTNeNt</mark>'
var reg = /<([\w]+)[ \w=\"]+>([\w]+)<\/\1>/g
input.replace(reg, '$2')
```

Output: `"coTNeNt"`

Comment: @Hawkeye Only YelColBox: `/<([\w]+) class="YelColBox">([\w]+)<\/\1>/g`

Comment: @Hawkeye Never BluColBox, but always any other color: `/<([\w]+) class="(?!Blu)[A-Z][a-z]{2}ColBox">([\w]+)<\/\1>/g`